# Through-the-Web Web Application Development

Tags: python, ruby

I'm particularly fond of the way the following SAAS companies have enabled application development through-the-web.  Many of them allow, through-the-web definition of tables, views, relationships, forms, dashboards, email-notifications, charts, calendars, cross-tabulations, and role based security.  They are:

- DabbleDB
- [Zoho](https://www.zoho.com)
- TeamDesk
- InfoDome
- [Caspio](https://www.caspio.com)

Other Interesting PAAS

- TIBCOSilver

I've also found these open source products that offer through-the-web application development.  These tend to use Javascript components that interface via a REST interface.  The Javascripts components can typically be switched into "development" mode and configured to have custom data sources, respond to events, and be styled.

- [WaveMaker](https://www.wavemaker.com) (Open Source Java)
- SmartGWTPro
- AribaWeb

Are there any other through-the-web application development frameworks?  I'm especially looking for the closest thing offered by Ruby or Python?

Comment: Your tags are pretty much way off. web and web-development seems good, java/python/ruby not so much.

Comment: I updated the question and the tags.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you mean with development.

[Zope 2](http://zope2.zope.org) is the original through-the-web (I'll say TTW from now on) development platform, and has done TTW dev since 1998 or so. It's in Python and is awesome in many ways. The TTW development is *not* one of those ways. :)

Creating forms and schemas, and editing the workflow etc TTW is a great idea. Calling it development is, well, not so great. :) Zope lets you write Python code. That is real TTW development, and it's a bad idea for many reasons.

- You can't use a proper editor.
- You can't use a debugger.
- You can't use a real version control system.
- etc etc for ever.

Now big, advanced deep configuration TTW, including schemas and workflows, yes. TTW Development, no. Bad idea.

The excellent CMS [Plone](http://plone.org/), which runs on Zope 2, is moving away from TTW development (although it's still possible and supported in Plone 4, just frowned upon), but still allows TTW configaration of large parts, including workflow, forms and with Dexterity (which is it's new content type framework) also content type Schemas.

Comment: YES!  I OG Zope user, back from the days before ZPTs and Plone.  However, I migrated to Rails in 2004.  My problem with Zope was that it placed the ZObject in an Object database, and I didn't really feel like the relational database was in center attention. also recall that Zope's version of through-the-web application development felt like regular coding, but through a

Comment: I completely agree that with Zope2 you really just feel like your using a text-box to code instead of your IDE of choice.  You also feel like your using a ZODB to store your source code instead of your choice of source code management systems.

Comment: Right, relational DB wasn't the center of attention, because the ZODB **rocks!** Otherwise you are quite right.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into Netzke http://demo.netzke.org/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Zenbase](http://getzenbase.com) platform as well.

It's web-based platform for non-coders to create data-driven web apps using a simple GUI.

Some of it's features:

- Built-in cloud CRUD-ready database solution based on phpGrid.
- User management - role and table-based permissions allow for strict data control.
- Data imports of CSV files to build new tables or add data to existing ones.
- Interactive and easy to generate reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for tools allowing you to create a software without coding, you have different tool categories:

- **"low code" platforms** (or workflow platforms), such as SalesForce, Appian/Mendix/OutSystems...
- **online database generators**, such as DBFace
- **code generators**, such as PHPMaker -windows tool- (i'm using it, very productive !) or ScriptCase (web based)
- and obviously **dashboarding tools**, such as KlipFolio, InfoCaptor (saas tool, but can be downloaded on your desktop/server)

**In OpenSource :**

you have the CMS Drupal, allowing you to create you data structure, then display listings (with module "Views") and forms...

You can create a complete Web based Software with Drupal and his tons of modules...

You can install and test Drupal online here : https://simplytest.me/